# Calculating the area of a triangle using methods in the System.Math class (C#)

Tags: c#, class, math, methods, geometry

I am studying C# and found this practice problem:

Write a program that calculates the area of a triangle with the following given:
the lengths of two sides and the angle between them (hint: side-angle-side)

I know how to find the area of a triangle in C# if I have the base and the height, and I know that there's a way to use the .Cos method in the .Math class in order to get the cosine that I need for my problem. However, my program does not seem to like the syntax that I am using. May I have any advice for how to implement methods in the .Math class in order to solve a geometry problem like this that takes user input for the side, the angle, and the other side?

I know that the formula is
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab * cos(y)   //where y = the degree of the angle

Here is what I have so far, which I think will get across what I am trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace day_of_the_week
{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            double side1;
            double side2;
            double angle;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter one side length.");
            side1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the other side's height.");
            side2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of the angle.");
            angle = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            double thirdside = Program.thirdside(side1, side2);
            Console.WriteLine(thirdside);
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
      public static double thirdside(double side1, double side2, double angle)
        {
            return (side1*side1 +  side2*side2 - 2*side1*side2.Cos(angle));
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"my program does not seem to like the syntax that I am using"* is not a sufficient description of your problem. Please include the error your get, and highlight the line that the error occurs in. Ideally take the time to remove all lines unrelated to the error, and present only a minimal code example. That said, in your case the most obvious error is trivial. Have you tried looking at the manual page for Math.Cos (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It contains examples and all that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mostly a maths problem (the formula is wrong/incomplete) combined with invalid syntax due to typos.

Comment: Btw. the correct formula for the area would be `(side1 * side2 * Math.Sin(angle)) / 2.0`.

Comment: @poke He doesn't want to know the area. He wants the third side by using the cosine rule, as per the expression in the question text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *“Write a program that calculates the area of a triangle […]”* plus the question title sounds pretty much like the area is the target value here.

Comment: @Poke The question is very garbled I grant you. User seems very confused. But it is like that when one is a total novice. Question later says: *May I have any advice for how to implement methods in the .Math class in order to solve a geometry problem like this that takes user input for the side, the angle, and the other side?* And then the question has a (broken) function named `thirdside`. This all matches the expression in the question text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, that parts sounds more like a “I have no idea how to solve this, so I’ll throw any formula I might remember at it, and see if that helps.” – But in any case, us discussing this is getting nowhere; it’s up for OP to decide. And besides, I still think this is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your function with calls to `Math.Cos` and `Math.Sqrt`, like this:

```
public static double rad(double deg)
{
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;  
}

public static double thirdside(double side1, double side2, double angleDeg)
{
    double angleRad = rad(angleDeg);
    return Math.Sqrt(side1*side1 + side2*side2 - 2*side1*side2*Math.Cos(angleRad));
}
```

Bear in mind that it is likely that you will want to input the angle in degrees. But `Math.Cos` accepts the angle in radians, hence the conversion.

And the code in the question neglected to take the square root of the expression. The code in this answer does so.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify class. so that is `Math.Cos(angle)`. Also use `Math.Pow(side1, 2)` to square numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the area of the triangle is

```
0.5*side1*side2*sin(toRadians(angle))
```

if `angle` is the angle between `side1` and `side2`.